# Why does setCustomAnimations persist even AFTER transactions in nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

This is a bit hard to explain in words and snippets. So I have prepared a simple project that reproduces the problem.

[Download](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_kROWNW348tQ1YtSDNjU2tyNVE/edit?usp=sharing) (File -> Download)

Upon initial run, you see `Activity A`, hosting `Fragment F`, which in turn hosts an additional nested fragment `Fragment F1`. When you press the **Fragment F Button**, you will see `Fragment F1` transitions into `Fragment F2` with animation (I deliberately made the animation slow so you can see the problem later on).

Now press the back key on your device, you will see `Fragment F2` transitions back into `Fragment F1`. (thanks to `addToBackStack`) All works fine, now press **Activity A Button**. You will see `Fragment F` transitions into `Fragment X`.

Pay careful attention as you press the back key now. You will see `Fragment X` transitions back into `Fragment F` as expected. However, it seems that now the active **nested fragment** (either `Fragment F1` or `Fragment F2`, depending on which one is visible) **is also transitioning** with the animations set from the previous `setCustomAnimations` call!

I was under the impression that `setCustomAnimations` is only effective for the applied `FragmentTransaction`, not for the whole fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. If anyone has better ideas, please let me know.

The `Fragment` class has a field named `mNextAnim` for storing its animation IDs.

```
// If app has requested a specific animation, this is the one to use.
int mNextAnim;
```

`android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord` is the internal implementation class for `FragmentTransaction`. During transaction, it sets the `mNextAnim` field to the appropriate animation ID, but does not clear it afterwards.

```
Field na = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mNextAnim");
na.setAccessible(true);
na.set(fragF1, 0);
```